# lines appearing in the color key and histogram of heatmap.2 in R

Tags: r, heatmap

Does anybody know about the lines in "color key and histogram" of heatmap.2 in R? When I produce the heatmap, some lines are appearing in the color key section which I don't know what they are representing. (green lines in the picture below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They are the histogram of the number times each data appears in the matrix that is being used in the heatmap. So if most of the values are 0 you will have a big "bump" in zero. That is also why, when you normalize the values in the heatmap, the distribution of this histogram looks like a normal distribution.